# Estaba utilizand el paquete de flutter launcher icons y al cambiar el icono me comenzo a salir este error : Invalid <color> for given resource value

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

el error completo es este:
C:....gradle\caches\transforms-3\5e083c06c9925c2309f02468fc66e376\transformed\core-1.7.0\res\values\values.xml:5:4: Invalid  for given resource value.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ResourceCompilerRunnable
> Resource compilation failed. Check logs for details.

Ya he intentado:
limpiar el cache de gradle,
deshacer el cambio de icono,
downgrade gradle.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Debes colocar el código que has implementado, para este caso lo requerido para flutter_launcher_icons, que se debe escribir en el pubspec.yaml, o si creaste flutter_launcher_icons.yaml, también más información de la versión de flutter que tienes. La versión de gradle, etc.
Pero por si no has probado te recomiendo actualizar la versión de gradle a una más nueva, o ir probando versiones para ver si alguna te funciona.
Igualmente te dejo algo que puede estar relacionado
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764604/execution-failed-for-task-appmergedebugresources-crunching-cruncher-png-fa
Pero para darte una mejor respuesta pues es necesario tener más información.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ya solucione el problema , primeramente intente poner una imagen con .ico y luego cambie a .png , y ya cuando hice esto  me empezo  a salir el error , basicamente lo q hice fue hacer un nuevo proyecto desde 0 , ya q aunque borrara todos los cambios seguia dando el mismo error